# Joomla Virtue Mart Language

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I'm using Joomla virtuemart for a Japanese site. I've found that when I use name or any other field in Japanese (or any other language than English) it doesn't work. its redirected to the registration form. But when I fill every field in English, it works.

I've checked that, when I insert data directly to the database, the data saves into it. but from the site it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the problem of permission. Virtuemart doesnot allow you to use Japanese.To solve this problem you must search Language plugins for Japanese.